# Is there a plugin or simple way to add a multiple images metabox to a post?

Tags: images, uploads, cms

I am looking for a way to create a custom field/metabox that allow to attach **multiple** and **infinite** images to a post. This would allow to create a custom post type for a portfolio and allow to attach images **without pasting them inside the post textarea**.

Most plugins I've seen allow for only 1 image. I've got the inspiration from the awesome [ProcessWire CMS](http://processwire.com/), that allows for this functionality right out of the box. It would be awesome to have this in Wordpress too!

Is there a plugin I'm missing? Could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cab be done very easy by custom code or using [`Meta Box Script For WordPress`](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box-script-for-wordpress/) which makes my life a lot easier when it comes to creating custom meta boxes.

Comment: Thanks Bainternet! I've figured this one could be close. Some example code could really help me out as I'm a pretty new WP developer! :)

Comment: Not that I'm lazy but this Script looks a little bit too intimidating to me right now